# How to get around JS/Jquery animation code flow bugs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Here's the thing, I'm using Jquery to add an event listener to various LI's for basic tab functionality (I followed a guide). I't seems to work a-ok unless the user speed clicks the LI's which seems to make the code stop or skip before it finishes rendering one of the content tabs.

The only things I could think of to get around this was add some code to make sure it finishes displaying properly before running his next queued click, but then if he clicks multiples at a time they will train run... so I'm unsure, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(".tab-panels .tabs li").on("click", tab);
function tab() {
    var $location = $(this).closest(".tab-panels");
    var $panel = $(this).attr("rel");
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $($location).find(".tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        $($location).find(".panel.active").slideUp(300, panelShow);
    }
    //$($location).find(".panel.active").removeClass("active");

    function panelShow() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("#" + $panel).slideDown(300);
        $("#" + $panel).addClass("active");
    }

}
```

```css
/*#region tabs*/
.tab-panels ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.tab-panels ul li:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
}

.tab-panels ul li.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
}

.tab-panels .panel {
    display:none;
    background: #c9c9c9;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.tab-panels .panel.active {
    display:block;
}
/*#endregion*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-panels">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li rel="panel1" class="active">panel1</li>
                <li rel="panel2">panel2</li>
                <li rel="panel3">panel3</li>
                <li rel="panel4">panel4</li>
            </ul>

            <div id="panel1" class="panel active">
                content1<br/>
                content1<br/>
                content1<br/>
                content1<br/>
                content1<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel2" class="panel">
                content2<br/>
                content2<br/>
                content2<br/>
                content2<br/>
                content2<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel3" class="panel">
                content3<br/>
                content3<br/>
                content3<br/>
                content3<br/>
                content3<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel4" class="panel">
                content4<br/>
                content4<br/>
                content4<br/>
                content4<br/>
                content4<br/>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="tab-panels">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li rel="panel5" class="active">panel5</li>
                <li rel="panel6">panel6</li>
                <li rel="panel7">panel7</li>
                <li rel="panel8">panel8</li>
            </ul>

            <div id="panel5" class="panel active">
                content5<br/>
                content5<br/>
                content5<br/>
                content5<br/>
                content5<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel6" class="panel">
                content6<br/>
                content6<br/>
                content6<br/>
                content6<br/>
                content6<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel7" class="panel">
                content7<br/>
                content7<br/>
                content7<br/>
                content7<br/>
                content7<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="panel8" class="panel">
                content8<br/>
                content8<br/>
                content8<br/>
                content8<br/>
                content8<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Ps: I also tried removing the panelShow function and adding a class removal the next line over, which fixed the bug but then added a hiccup when first running the code and switching from the default panel showing to another.

Comment: Here's the codePen I was basing it off of: 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyQez?editors=1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the animations with [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
...").stop().slideDown(...)
...").stop().slideUp(...)
```